# Magento Tier Sales Prices?

Tags: oop, magento, zend-framework, promotions

I've been trying to mirror some functionality 
in Magento (v1.6) as seen on another website. In the example, the
store owner has set up the ability to apply sales prices to a tier.
(most likely tierprices.phtml as the wrapper) by applying a sales price
(most likely in admin / product / price sales)

I've been working on figuring out exactly how it is done, but haven't
made any headway on it insofar. Does anyone have any idea how this was
constructed?

Here's the example website
http://www.epromos.com/product/2801001.html

Here's the Table code:

```
    if($_tierPrices) {
        echo '<style>
                .strikeRow      {text-decoration: line-through;}
                .saleRow td     {color:red;}
                .quantityRow    {background: #eef} 
                td              {padding:3px 9px; border: 1px solid #fc0;} 
            </style>';          // temporary styling

        $q = "<td>Quantity</td>";
        $p = "<td>{$_product->getName()}</td>";
        $s = "<td>Reduced Price</td>";

        foreach ($_tierPrices as &$tier) { 
        #$tier['tier_sale'] = '0.00';   // trick the dump into thinking there is a product sale
            if($tier['price_qty'])      { $q .= "<td>{$tier['price_qty']}</td>"; }
            if($tier['price'])          { $p .= "<td>".number_format($tier['price'], 2, '.', '')."</td>"; }
            if($tier['tier_sale'])      { $s .= "<td>{$tier['tier_sale']}</td>"; }
        }

        $q = "<tr class='quantityRow'>{$q}</tr>";
        $p = ($_tierPrices[0]['tier_sale'])? "<tr class='strikeRow'>{$p}</tr>"  : "<tr>{$p}</tr>";
        $s = ($_tierPrices[0]['tier_sale'])? "<tr class='saleRow'>{$s}</tr>"    : '';

        echo "<tbody>$q $p $s</tbody></table>";

    }
```

And the full source:

```
<?php
/**
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
 */
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_tierPrices = $this->getTierPrices();
$_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice(), true);

/** @var $_catalogHelper Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data */
$_catalogHelper = Mage::helper('catalog');

$_weeeTaxAmount = Mage::helper('weee')->getAmountForDisplay($_product);

if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_product, array(1,2,4))) {
    $_weeeTaxAttributes = Mage::helper('weee')->getProductWeeeAttributesForDisplay($_product);
}

 if (count($_tierPrices) > 0) { 

    // start table group with class type if  (obj)getInGrouped() == 1
    echo ($this->getInGrouped()) ? '<table class="tier-prices-grouped product-pricing-grouped">' : '<table class="tier-prices product-pricing">'; 

    // assign tier pricing to $_tierPrices
    if ($this->getInGrouped()) {
         $_tierPrices = $this->getTierPrices($_product);
    }

        Mage::helper('weee')->processTierPrices($_product, $_tierPrices);

    foreach ($_tierPrices as $_price) {

        echo '<tr>';

        if ($_catalogHelper->canApplyMsrp($_product)) {

            if ($this->getInGrouped()) {

                echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for', $_price['price_qty']) .':';

            } else { 

                echo $this->__('Buy %1$s', $_price['price_qty']);

            } 

        } else {

                if ($this->helper('tax')->displayBothPrices()) {

                    if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_product, 0)) {

                        echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s (%3$s incl. tax) each', $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price_incl_weee_only'], $_price['formated_price_incl_weee']);

                    } elseif(Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_product, 1)) {

                            echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s', $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price_incl_weee_only']);

                            if ($_weeeTaxAttributes) {

                                echo '(<small>';
                                echo $this->__('%1$s incl tax.', $_price['formated_price_incl_weee']);

                                $separator = ' + '; 

                                    foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_attribute) {

                                        echo $separator;
                                        echo $_attribute->getName() .': '. Mage::helper('core')->currency($_attribute->getAmount());

                                    }

                                echo '</small>)';

                            }

                            echo $this->__('each');

                    } elseif(Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_product, 4)) {

                            echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s', $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price_incl_weee_only']);

                            if ($_weeeTaxAttributes) {

                                echo '(<small>';
                                echo $this->__('%1$s incl tax.', $_price['formated_price_incl_weee']);

                                $separator = ' + '; 

                                    foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_attribute) {

                                        echo $separator;
                                        echo $_attribute->getName() .': '. Mage::helper('core')->currency($_attribute->getAmount()+$_attribute->getTaxAmount());

                                    }

                                echo '</small>)';

                            }

                            echo $this->__('each');

                    } elseif(Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_product, 2)) {

                            echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s', $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price']);

                            if ($_weeeTaxAttributes) {

                                echo '(<small>';

                                    foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_attribute) {

                                        echo $_attribute->getName() .': '. Mage::helper('core')->currency($_attribute->getAmount());

                                    }

                                echo $this->__('Total incl. Tax: %1$s', $_price['formated_price_incl_weee']);
                                echo '</small>)';

                            }

                            echo $this->__('each');

                    } else {

                            echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s (%3$s incl. tax) each', $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price'], $_price['formated_price_incl_tax']);

                    }

                } else {

                    if ($this->helper('tax')->displayPriceIncludingTax()) {

                        if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_product, 0)) {

                                echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s each', $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price_incl_weee']);

                        } elseif(Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_product, 1)) {

                                echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s', $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price_incl_weee']);

                                if ($_weeeTaxAttributes) {

                                    echo '(<small>';
                                    $separator = ''; 

                                    foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_attribute) {

                                            echo $separator;
                                            echo $_attribute->getName() .': '. Mage::helper('core')->currency($_attribute->getAmount());

                                        $separator = ' + '; 

                                    }

                                    echo '</small>)';

                                }

                                echo $this->__('each');

                        } elseif(Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_product, 4)) { 

                                echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s', $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price_incl_weee']);

                                if ($_weeeTaxAttributes) {

                                    echo '(<small>';
                                    $separator = ''; 

                                    foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_attribute) {

                                            echo $separator;
                                            echo $_attribute->getName() .': '. Mage::helper('core')->currency($_attribute->getAmount()+$_attribute->getTaxAmount());

                                        $separator = ' + ';

                                    } 

                                    echo '</small>)';

                                }

                                echo $this->__('each');

                        } elseif(Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_product, 2)) {

                                echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s', $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price_incl_tax']);

                                if ($_weeeTaxAttributes) {

                                    echo '(<small>';

                                        foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_attribute) {

                                            echo $_attribute->getName() .': '. Mage::helper('core')->currency($_attribute->getAmount());

                                        }

                                    echo $this->__('Total incl. Tax: %1$s', $_price['formated_price_incl_weee']);
                                    echo '</small>)';

                                }

                                echo $this->__('each');

                        } else {

                                echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s each', $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price_incl_tax']);
                        }

                    } else {

                        if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_product, 0)) {

                                echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s each', $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price_incl_weee_only']);

                        } elseif(Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_product, 1)) {

                                echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s', $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price_incl_weee_only']);

                                if ($_weeeTaxAttributes) {

                                    echo '(<small>';
                                    $separator = ''; 

                                        foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_attribute) {

                                            echo $separator;
                                            echo $_attribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_attribute->getAmount());

                                        $separator = ' + '; 

                                        }

                                    echo '</small>)';

                                }

                                echo $this->__('each');

                        } elseif(Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_product, 4)) {

                                echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s', $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price_incl_weee_only']);

                                if ($_weeeTaxAttributes) {

                                    echo '(<small>';
                                    $separator = ''; 

                                        foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_attribute) {

                                            echo $separator;
                                            echo $_attribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_attribute->getAmount()+$_attribute->getTaxAmount());

                                        $separator = ' + '; 

                                        }

                                    echo '</small>)';

                                }

                                echo $this->__('each');

                        } elseif(Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_product, 2)) {

                                echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s', $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price']);

                                if ($_weeeTaxAttributes) {

                                    echo '(<small>';

                                        foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_attribute) {

                                            echo $_attribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_attribute->getAmount());

                                        }

                                    echo $this->__('Total incl. Tax: %1$s', $_price['formated_price_incl_weee_only']);
                                    echo '</small>)';

                                }

                                echo $this->__('each');

                        } else {

                                // concern
                                //echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s each', $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price']);

                                $priceSchema['quantity'][] =  $_price['price_qty'];
                                $priceSchema['formated_price'][] =  $_price['formated_price'];

                        }


                    } 

        }


        } // Can apply MSRP

        if (!$this->getInGrouped()) {

        // we need this ~

            // funky ass OR switch, can i rework this in a saner way?
            if( ($_product->getPrice() == $_product->getFinalPrice() && $_product->getPrice() > $_price['price'])
             || ($_product->getPrice() != $_product->getFinalPrice() &&  $_product->getFinalPrice() > $_price['price']) ) {

//               echo ' '. $this->__('and') .'&nbsp;<strong class="benefit">'. $this->__('save') .'&nbsp;'. $_price['savePercent'] .'%';

            } 

//          echo '</strong>'; // why the hell isn't this in the OR switch??? 

        // we need this ~

        }

        if ($_catalogHelper->isShowPriceOnGesture($_product)) {

            $popupId = 'msrp-popup-' . $_product->getId() . $this->helper('core')->getRandomString(20);

            echo '<a href="#" id="'. $popupId .'">'. $this->__('Click for price') .'</a>';
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

            if (!$this->getInGrouped()) {

                echo 'var newLink = {';

                    echo 'url: "'. $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product, array('qty' => $_price['price_qty'])) .'",';
                    echo 'qty: "'. $_price['price_qty'] .'"';

                echo '};';

            } else {

                echo 'var newLink = {';

                    echo 'url: "'. $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product, array('qty' => $_price['price_qty'])) .'",';
                    echo 'notUseForm: true';

                echo '};';

            }

                echo 'Catalog.Map.addHelpLink(';

                    echo "$('{$popupId}'),";
                    echo '"'. $_product->getName() .'",';
                    echo json_encode($_price['real_price_html']) .',';
                    echo '"'. $this->helper('core')->currency($_product->getMsrp(),true,false) .'",';
                    echo 'newLink';

                echo ');';

            echo '</script>';

        } else {

            echo '<span class="msrp-price-hide-message">'. $_catalogHelper->getMsrpPriceMessage($_product) .'</span>';

        }

    }
}

    if($_tierPrices) {
        echo '<style>
                .strikeRow      {text-decoration: line-through;}
                .saleRow td     {color:red;}
                .quantityRow    {background: #eef} 
                td              {padding:3px 9px; border: 1px solid #fc0;} 
            </style>';          // temporary styling

        $q = "<td>Quantity</td>";
        $p = "<td>{$_product->getName()}</td>";
        $s = "<td>Reduced Price</td>";

        foreach ($_tierPrices as &$tier) { 
        #$tier['tier_sale'] = '0.00';   // trick the dump into thinking there is a product sale
            if($tier['price_qty'])      { $q .= "<td>{$tier['price_qty']}</td>"; }
            if($tier['price'])          { $p .= "<td>".number_format($tier['price'], 2, '.', '')."</td>"; }
            if($tier['tier_sale'])      { $s .= "<td>{$tier['tier_sale']}</td>"; }
        }

        $q = "<tr class='quantityRow'>{$q}</tr>";
        $p = ($_tierPrices[0]['tier_sale'])? "<tr class='strikeRow'>{$p}</tr>"  : "<tr>{$p}</tr>";
        $s = ($_tierPrices[0]['tier_sale'])? "<tr class='saleRow'>{$s}</tr>"    : '';

        echo "<tbody>$q $p $s</tbody></table>";

    }
?>
```

Comment: How do you want it to work? Do you want the retail price for each of your tier prices to be calculated automatically based on some algorithm or do you want it to be input manually? btw, that other site is not Magento :-P

Comment: Honestly it doesn't matter if its a catalog rule, or can be entered as a percentage/total value in the admin panel. Anything will work, and I can always modify it later. Thanks for the resp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is quick solution for you.

You can use a 'cost' field of the product to define the percentage by which the retail price is higher then your price. By default 'cost' field is used as a memo of how much you paid for the product and is not used anywhere at the front-end.

Then go to templates/template/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml of your theme and add the following lines after `$_product = $this->getProduct();` line:

```
$multiplier = $_product->getData('cost');
$multiplier = $multiplier ? $multiplier : 1;
```

And the following line between `<?php endif; ?>` and `<?php if (!$this->getInGrouped()): ?>`:

```
Retail price: <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price['price']*$multiplier, true, false) ?>
```

I'm sure you will be able to style it as you wish. Please let me know if something is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure what you are looking for is absolute pricing for options regardless of tier, if so here is the link to how this could be accomplished:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/use-absolute-price-for-custom-options

Comment: There unfortunetly is a huge flaw in the Default.php with adding these options to the database. =(