# Create a tier price table/grid in Magento frontend

Tags: magento

I am trying to figure out how to format the tier pricing in Magento products detail page into a grid/table format.  For example, I would like to have a Quantity Row, Price row, and discount row.  And it about 5 columns.  Is this possible?   We sell products in bulk, so this layout is important.  That would be great if someone can point me in the right direct.  I am new to magento and finding the customization side of things difficult to pick up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I made the following template for my tierprices.phtml.

FYI I'm running Magento 1.8.x

```
<?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_tierPrices = $this->getTierPrices();
if (count($_tierPrices) > 0):
    $_data = array();
    $_prevQty = 0;
    $_counter = 0;
    $_tierPrices = array_reverse($_tierPrices);
    foreach ($_tierPrices as $_index => $_price){
        $_counter++;
        if($_price['price_qty']>$_prevQty){
            if($_counter == 1){
                $label = $_price['price_qty'] . '+';
            } else {
                $label = $this->__('%d or less',$_price['price_qty']);
            }
            $_data[] = array('prev'=>$_prevQty,'next'=>$_price['price_qty'],'label'=>$label,'price'=>$_price['formated_price']);
            $_prevQty = $_price['price_qty'];
        } else {
            $label = $_price['price_qty'] . '-' . $_prevQty;
            $_data[] = array('prev'=>$_prevQty,'next'=>$_price['price_qty'],'label'=>$label,'price'=>$_price['formated_price']);
            $_prevQty = $_price['price_qty'];
        }
    }
    $_data = array_reverse($_data);
?>
    <table class="tiered-pricing">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        <?php foreach ($_data as $_row): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $_row['label']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $_row['price']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

It makes a table version of the tiered pricing data.

Answer (score 0):

The following URL will be useful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257924/magento-tier-sales-prices

You can also modify the following template

```
magento/app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml
```

where you can loop through `$_tierPrices` array and generate html table element